# Ensure that all lines in a file match a known RegEx pattern, without relying on \A \z

Tags: javascript, regex

In a multi-line file I want to check that *all* lines match one or more complex patterns (which may each cover multiple lines).

I can make this work just fine with this RegEx

```
\A(patternA\n|patternB\n)*\z
```

(For some languages it works with `\Z` instead of `\z`)

It will match:

```
patternA
patternB
patternA
```

and will reject

```
patternA
patternC
patternB
```

But it does not work in JavaScript (where I need to execute the test) because JavaScript RegEx apparently does not support the anchors `\A` (start of file) or `\z` (end of file). And if those anchors are left off then I just get back a set of *matches* (the first and third lines in my second example above), without the information that there are also non-matches.

At the moment, the only thing I can think of is to run the RegEx check without those two anchors, and then check that the sum of the length of all the matches equals the length of the overall text, but this seems rather clunky.

Is there a simple/elegant way to implement this check in JavaScript RegEx?

Comment: But JS regex have `^` and `$` ...?

Comment: Please share a [mre] of what doesn't work.

Comment: @CBroe  ^ and $ match the beginning and end of a line, not the beginning and end of file

Comment: @kiner_shah  I've added \n (twice) to my original example. This makes it work with the two specific example below. You can try it in RegEx101 for example, first for Python then for ECMAScript (JavaScript) RegEx.

Comment: _"^ and $ match the beginning and end of a line, not the beginning and end of file"_ - that totally depends on whether you set the multiline modifier, or not.

Comment: @CBroe  I have tried it in RegEx101 with both the multi-line modifier on and off. Does not work either way.

Comment: For python it didn't work, I had to replace `\z` with `\Z`. For javascript it didn't match.

Comment: I can't even get your original pattern to do anything on regex101, even if I chose python. Please provide a link via the Save&Share functionality of that site.

Comment: Some implementations require \z and some with \Z. As @kiner_shah pointed out Python requires the upper-case Z not z (as I had it in example). But the point is that neither works with JavaScript RegEx.

Comment: Richard, CBroe [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73442676/ensurse-that-all-lines-in-a-file-match-a-known-regex-pattern-without-relying-on#comment129696934_73442676). `$` in JS matches the very end of string if you do not use `m` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I now think the best solution may be to invert logic so that it searches for anything that does *not* match the required patterns, and passes the check if *no* match is found. The following RegEx, running under JavaScript, for example, matches the second example from my original post and not the first:

```
^(?!patternA$|patternB$|$)
```

The last option (`$`) is needed as otherwise it always matches the (empty) line following the last newline.

Answer (score 0):

If the individual patterns are complex, it may be both easier on the regex engine and simpler to understand to write imperative code that loops through each of the lines and checks for each of the patterns in order.

This will let each of the patterns stay one regex. They do not have to be baked into the "whole file" pattern when one is updated, added or removed. The different patterns can also use different regex flags and so on.